# android 2.2 emulator -- Fails to load Wi-Fi driver

Tags: android-emulator, android-wifi

I can't connect my emulator -- Target: Android 2.2 -- to connect to my home wifi that I know works ok. (Had also been able to do that a couple of months ago.) The emulator displays "(No Service)" on top right of start screen. LogCat shows:

> 10-26 05:53:16.531: INFO/WifiService(60): WifiService starting up with Wi-Fi disabled
>   ...
>   10-26 05:57:44.963: ERROR/WifiService(60): Failed to load Wi-Fi driver.

Have tried running Dev Tools > Connectivity > Enable Wifi, but only see another "Failed to load Wi-Fi driver entry in LogCat.

But emulator -- Target: GoogleAPIs on Platform 2.1-update1 -- displays "Android" on top right, and seems to connect to the same home wifi fine. Eclipse and emulator run on my Windows XP laptop.

Appreciate any insights...
CL

Answer (score 1):

The emulator will do networking, but the wifi doesn't load a driver due to not being able to access the host hardware.

You need to test wifi code natively.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter such problem when trying to perform WiFi scanning from the emulator. However when i tried running the program on my physical device, no such problem encountered.